# Removing last comma from string (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

How can I remove the last comma from this loop code(wordpress)?

```
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category){ 
echo $category->name.", ";
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using wp_list_categories? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ( ( get_the_category() ) as $category ) {  
    $cats[] = $category->name;
}
echo implode ( ', ', $cats );
```